# How can I add type hints for my custom global Vue directives?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, volar

I can get TypeScript hints if I import or create a directive in a SFC file as follows:

```
import vFocus from 'my-custom-component-library';
```

[demo with ts hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SPUW.png)

Howerver, if I register it globally in `main.ts`, I cannot get the type hints.

For example:

```
app.directive('focus', vFocus);
```

[demo without ts hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnCtr.png)

So how can I add type hints if I want to globally install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `vue-language` [issue 465](https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/issues/465), currently I can declare the Directives in `ComponentCustomProperties` for global register directives but it may pollution component global properties.

```
// shim-vue.d.ts
import vFocus from 'my-custom-component-library'

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
    export interface ComponentCustomProperties {
        vFocus: typeof vFocus;
    }
}

export { }
```